# Write full box to topology file + script representation

Tags: vmd

I would like `topo writelammpsdata` to print the full box, while it seems only to be printing one molecule.

I have loaded several molecules in a box with VMD - here working with water and benzene as an example.
Although the box looks alright, I am not able to correctly topo writelammpsdata.
Essentially, while I have N molecules, the lt file produced only contains 1 molecule.

I paste the whole script and the initial files. Please note that I am translating each molecule and picking alternatively a water or a benzene molecule.
Also, is there a way to script a representation in VMD? Say I want each water to be licorice.

```
set side 50
set nmol_per_side 2

## Replicate the molecule

mol new water.pdb
set mol_idx 0

for {set i 0} {$i <= $nmol_per_side} {incr i} {
  for {set j 0} {$j <= $nmol_per_side} {incr j} {
    for {set k 0} {$k <= $nmol_per_side} {incr k} {

        set dx [expr $side/$nmol_per_side*$i]
    set dy [expr $side/$nmol_per_side*$j]
        set dz [expr $side/$nmol_per_side*$k]

        if { ($dx != 0) || ($dy != 0) || ($dz != 0) } {
        incr mol_idx
        puts "dx = $dx, dy = $dy, dz = $dz, mol_idx = $mol_idx"


            if { ($mol_idx % 2)==0 } {
           mol new water.pdb
        } else {
           mol new benzene.pdb
           }
        set molecule [atomselect $mol_idx "all"]
            $molecule moveby [ list $dx $dy $dz ]

            }
      }
    }
  }

# Create a cubic box
pbc set [ list $side $side $side ]
pbc box

topo retypebonds
topo guessangles
topo guessdihedrals

topo writelammpsdata full_box.lt full
```

You can really use any molecule. Here I am using water:

```
ATOM      1  O   HOH     1       0.000   0.000   0.000  1.00  0.00           O  
ATOM      2  H1  HOH     1       0.957   0.000   0.000  1.00  0.00           H  
ATOM      3  H2  HOH     1      -0.239   0.927   0.000  1.00  0.00           H  
CONECT    1    2    3  
CONECT    2    1  
CONECT    3    1
```

and benzene:

```
ATOM      1  C   BEN     1       0.000   1.402   0.000  1.00  0.00           C  
ATOM      2  C   BEN     1       1.214   0.701   0.000  1.00  0.00           C  
ATOM      3  C   BEN     1       1.214  -0.701   0.000  1.00  0.00           C  
ATOM      4  C   BEN     1       0.000  -1.402   0.000  1.00  0.00           C  
ATOM      5  C   BEN     1      -1.214  -0.701   0.000  1.00  0.00           C  
ATOM      6  C   BEN     1      -1.214   0.701   0.000  1.00  0.00           C  
ATOM      7  H   BEN     1       0.000   2.494   0.000  1.00  0.00           H  
ATOM      8  H   BEN     1       2.156   1.247   0.000  1.00  0.00           H  
ATOM      9  H   BEN     1       2.156  -1.247   0.000  1.00  0.00           H  
ATOM     10  H   BEN     1       0.000  -2.788   0.000  1.00  0.00           H  
ATOM     11  H   BEN     1      -2.156  -1.247   0.000  1.00  0.00           H  
ATOM     12  H   BEN     1      -2.156   1.247   0.000  1.00  0.00           H  
CONECT    1    2    6  
CONECT    2    1    3  
CONECT    3    2    4  
CONECT    4    3    5  
CONECT    5    4    6  
CONECT    6    1    5  
CONECT    1    7  
CONECT    2    8  
CONECT    3    9  
CONECT    4   10  
CONECT    5   11  
CONECT    6   12
```

Thank you

Marco

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per [documentation](https://sites.google.com/site/akohlmey/software/topotools/documentation) (search for "molid"), TopoTools only works on one "VMD molecule" at a time, and by default this is just `mol top`. Your approach adds each new molecule to a new VMD molecule, and thus `writelammpsdata` writes only the last molecule you've created.

In your situation, the workflow I would adopt is:

1. Use `writelammpsdata` to convert `water.pdb` and `benzene.pdb` *each* to separate LAMMPS data files.
2. Read them both into a LAMMPS script using *successive* `read_data` commands (with the needed keywords, especially `extra/*` and `offset`).
3. In the same script, use `replicate` to multiply the water and benzene to the necessary quantity.
4. Equilibrate well (possibly at high temperature), adjusting the box size manually as desired.

Ordinarily I would recommend [PACKMOL](https://m3g.github.io/packmol/), which will combine `water.pdb` and `benzene.pdb` into (for example) `90water+70benzene.pdb`, with some randomisation of coordinates to boot. You could then load that into VMD as a single molecule and `topo writelammpsdata` into a LAMMPS data file. But, for benzene, I imagine you need some care defining the dihedrals and impropers, and you might prefer to `replicate` in LAMMPS and *know* that all the benzenes have the same dihedral representation, rather than having TopoTools independently convert each one from PDB (or VMD's internal representation).